# What kind of words can be followed by the character 感？

Tags: grammar, word

For example:

> 正义**感**
>
> 使命**感**
>
> 厚重**感**

But some sound weird to me, as [意义感](http://archive.is/eFtrM).

Is there a rule?

Comment: As a native speaker but not an expert in grammar I'd say the word before 感 should be something your could feel or get emotionally aroused. Thus I don't think 意义感 is valid, and I've never heard people say so.

Comment: @PJ.Hades, thanks for your reply. I learned it from [here](http://archive.is/eFtrM)

Comment: IMHO I note that in your given sentence 意义感 is more like a term created by the quoted person. Thus these created words may escape from the general grammar "rules".

Comment: @PJ.Hades, indeed. You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

For illustration purpose, I compiled a list of words ending by 感 fetched from [moedict](https://www.moedict.tw/).

Here is a words-list with English explanation.

```
傷感: sad, emotional, sentimental, pathos
動感: sense of movement (often in a static work of art), dynamic, vivid, lifelike
反感: to be disgusted with, to dislike, bad reaction, antipathy
口感: taste, texture (of food), how food feels in the mouth
同感: (have the) same feeling, similar impression, common feeling
善感: sensitive, emotional
喜感: comicality, comical, (Buddhism) joy
多愁善感: melancholy and moody (idiom); depressed personality
好感: good opinion, favorable impression
安全感: sense of security
幽默感: sense of humor
快感: pleasure, thrill, delight, joy, pleasurable sensation, a high
性冷感: frigidity (lack of libido)
性感: sex appeal, eroticism, sexuality, sexy
情感: feeling, emotion, to move (emotionally)
惡感: malice, ill will
感: to feel, to move, to touch, to affect, feeling, emotion, (suffix) sense of 
手感: the feel (of sth touched with the hand), (textiles) handle
敏感: sensitive, susceptible
無力感: feeling of powerlessness, sense of helplessness
痛感: to feel deeply, acute suffering
第六感: sixth sense (i.e. intuition, premonition, telepathy etc)
罪惡感: feeling of guilt
美感: sense of beauty, aesthetic perception
肉感: sexiness, sexy, sensuality, sensual, voluptuous
臨場感: the feeling of actually being there
觀感: one's impressions, observations
語感: a feel for language, instinctive understanding
讀後感: impression of a book, opinion expressed in a book review
責任感: sense of responsibility
質感: realism (in art), sense of reality, texture, tactile quality
遙感: remote sensing
雜感: random thoughts (a literary genre)
靈感: inspiration, insight, a burst of creativity in scientific or artistic endeavor
預感: to have a premonition, premonition
骨感: bony, skinny
```

The following words-list with Chinese definition is rather complete compared to the previous one (it contains words having no English translation).

```
交感：互相感應。
交感：性交。《初刻拍案驚奇．卷一七》：「此後恍恍惚惚，合眼就夢見吳氏來與他交感。」《二刻拍案驚奇．卷三○》：「遂欣然留與同宿，交感之際，一如人道。」也作「交會」。
今昔之感：從眼前的現狀回憶過去的情境。多表示對世事的感慨。
使命感：對某種重大責任，有應該擔負的自覺。
偶感：突然的感發。
傷感：有所感觸而悲傷。
優越感：心理上自覺超過他人。
動感：形容人活潑熱烈、魅力十足。
反感：反對或不滿的情緒。
口感：享用食物時的感覺。
可感：令人感動。
可感：感動。
同感：相同的感受或感想。
善感：容易引發感觸。
喜感：人在舉手投足之間，深具喜劇效果。
壓迫感：個人因外在因素的影響，產生的一種緊繃、不舒暢、侷促等的心理感受。
外感：受外來刺激而起的感動。
外感：中醫上指風寒暑溼自外侵入的病。
多愁善感：形容人感情脆弱，易憂愁傷感。
好感：對人對事有滿意或喜歡的感覺。
安全感：安全無虞的感覺。
幽默感：善於運用機智的言語或手法應對問題的能力。
律動感：有節奏變化的感覺。
快感：愉快或舒服的感覺。
性冷感：女子缺乏性慾的反常現象。
性冷感：性交時女子毫無樂趣的身心反應狀態。
性感：富有性的誘惑力。
悲傷感：文學、美術作品或臺上表演所描述的狀況，在讀者或觀眾心理上產生的憐憫、同情和悲傷。
悲感：心情悲傷。
情感：內心有所觸發，而產生喜、怒、哀、樂等的心理反應。
惡感：不好的感覺。
感：震撼。
感：接觸、引起。
感：覺得。
感：互相影響、應和。
感：傷嘆。
感：對別人所給的好處表示謝意。
感：受到外來刺激所引起的情緒反應。
感：某種自我認知的看法或想法。
慚感：感激。
應感：文藝創作過程中因外物而產生靈感的現象。
應感：特指天人感應。
應物斯感：因應外在的事物而有所感悟。
懷感：懷念感恩。
懷感：唐代一位高僧的法號。專修淨土法門，通釋關於往生淨土的疑難。對唐代淨土宗的發展，貢獻很大。著有《釋淨土群疑論》七卷。
成就感：付出努力後獲得成果的滿足感。
手感：用手觸摸時的感覺。
敏感：一種神經上的病態，對外界情況容易引起迅速而強烈的反應。
敏感：泛指心理、生理上超乎尋常程度的感受與反應。
敏感：尖銳的、容易引起是非的。
機感：佛教用語。早期的佛教徒認為眾生有善根之機，能感知佛意。
正義感：好善嫉惡，有維護正義、主持公理的心思與熱情。
民族優越感：以自己的民族為最優秀，將其他民族視為較低劣的心態。
無力感：心裡的願望，因受阻礙或能力才幹不能全然發揮，所產生的挫折感。
疏離感：因社會變遷與都市工業化的影響，使人在面對生活環境時，失去其原有的和諧與親密關係，終而形成現代人面對其生活周遭環境時，自覺無意義感、無能為力感、社會孤立感、自我分離感等複雜心態，稱為「疏離感」。
病識感：精神病患對自己所罹患的病症有自我察覺的意識。
痛感：深刻的感覺到。
百感：各種感想。比喻感受很多。
空間感：影片創作者根據透視原理，運用各種手法，如照明、光學、物體的不同顏色等，造成光影明暗、色彩的差別和對比，使其在平面的銀幕上獲得立體、縱深的感覺。
立體感：具有深度、方向的逼真感覺。
第六感：眼、耳、鼻、舌、身等五身器官感覺以外的特殊敏感，是一種直覺或靈感，具神祕色彩。
罪惡感：個人在實際行為上或想像中，因有違家庭、宗教或社會規範，引發內在良心譴責而感到愧疚難安的一種主觀意識經驗。
美感：對美的感覺與體認。
肉感：肉體所引發的刺激或感覺。
臨場感：如同在現場的感覺。
臨感：臨別的愁緒。
自卑感：個人對自己所具備的條件、言行等感到不滿的心理感受。通常由幼年時期逐漸形成，為人類的普遍現象。
自感：自己感覺。
自感：電路上的電流隨時間變化，而在本身產生感應電壓的現象。
至感：極其感激，常為書信用語。
至感：至誠的感通。
觀感：觀察人或事物後所得感想。
語感：對於語言文字之心理上的反應。如對「田園」一語，詩人所感在其閒適的情趣，而園藝家所感則在其實際的效用。
讀後感：看完文章或書本內容後的內心感受。
責任感：擔負責任的心理認識。
質感：對物品質地的感覺，如粗糙、細滑、柔軟、堅硬等。
遙感：近年新開發的探測技術，對遠距離的事物進行偵測或產生感應。參見「遙感探測」條。
量感：繪畫與雕塑製作中，使人在視覺上有輕重、厚薄、多少等感覺。如泥土的沉穩感、棉花的輕柔感等。
銘感：感激不忘。
雜感：即興而成的片段感想。
雜感：零星細碎，沒有條理、沒有組織的感想。
靈感：靈驗有感應。
靈感：思考活動中，忽然出現且超越平時思考層面的想法。
音感：對音色、音高等音樂現象的辨識能力。
預感：預料事情要發生的感覺。如：「我有不祥的預感，他可能會出事。」也作「豫感」。
風樹之感：比喻父母亡故，兒女不得奉養的悲傷。參見「風木含悲」條。
骨感：形容極為消瘦。
```

For those who are interested in the way to generate these lists, here is the bash script.

**English words-list**:

```
curl 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/g0v/moedict-data/master/dict-revised.json' | jq '.[] | select(.title | match("^.*感$")) | {title: .title, def: .heteronyms | .[0].definitions | .[0].def} | .title ' > results.txt
```

```
cat results.txt |  
while read -r a ; do 
    curl "https://www.moedict.tw/a/$(echo $a | tr -d '\"').json" | 
    jq '.translation.English as $en | {title: .t, en: $en | join(", ")} | [.title, .en] | join(": ")' | tr -d '`~\"' >> results-en.txt
done
```

**Chinese words-list**:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/g0v/moedict-data/master/dict-revised.json | jq '.[] | select(.title | match("^.*感$")) | {title: .title, def: .heteronyms | .[0].definitions | .[].def} | [.title, .def] | join("：")' | tr -d "\"" > results-zh.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

感我的理解是一种感觉，感受形容什么感主题应该是人。所以意义感不对。
I think the word 感 means feeling about sb，so when you use the word 感 ,it should describ sb’s feeling ,not something.

Answer (score -3):

There's no rule for this  XX感.

Just consider XX感 as a noun.